# 502 Proxy Error: The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, proxy

I'm trying to get my first web app working and am running into some issues when i try to deploy to server. I did some research but i can't seem to find how the solutions would apply to me. My app runs fine when i have on my local tomcat server, but when i try to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, i get a this proxy error. Below are all the details...

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>FirstSpringMVCProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>FirstSpringMVCProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.41</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>Web projects</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>DisplayMatchup.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


  <context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
 </bean>
```

DisplayMatchup.jsp (view)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<style>
ol {
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    font-family: Courier;
    text-align: center;
}
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Courier;
    white-space: normal;
}
</style>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Basketball Player Rater</title>
</head>
<h2>Basketball Player Rater</h2>
<body>
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://results.cae10gzzpyrn.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/results"
     user="yogidmt"  password="bearbpa10"/>
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY wins DESC;
</sql:query>
<ol>
<h2>Team 1</h2>
<form:form method="post" action="http://localhost/FirstSpringMVCProject/" modelAttribute="team">
<button type="submit" name="team" value="${matchup.teams[0]}${matchup.teams[1]}"/>${matchup.teams[0]}</button>
</form:form>
</ol>
<ol>
<h2>Team 2</h2>
<form:form method="post" action="http://localhost/FirstSpringMVCProject/" modelAttribute="team">
<button type="submit" name="team" value="${matchup.teams[1]}${matchup.teams[0]}"/>${matchup.teams[1]}</button>
</form:form>
</ol>
<h3>Results:</h3>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<c:out value="${row.player}"/> --- <c:out value="${row.winrate}"/>
</br>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloController.java (controller

```
package com.gontuseries.hellocontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView display() {     

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("DisplayMatchup");
        model.addObject("matchup", new Matchup());

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("team") String s) {
        Util.updateParse(s);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("DisplayMatchup");
        model.addObject("matchup", new Matchup());

        return model;
    }
}
```

I assume the rest my Java is irrelevant, works fine locally the only error i get is

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load .  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
Mar 23, 2017 10:27:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
```

But the app still seems to work fine.

This is all i get when i try to access the app

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Also [server logs](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-764662905079.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/tail/e-ig2xm3fgdn/i-0b69b1ed45bc825a9/TailLogs-1490282204705.out?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4EUBGPT4J56L5CQ&Expires=1490368606&Signature=%2FHZB38Br%2FJb7hSZeiQOj8gG4FWM%3D) (last 100 lines)

Comment: Configure the timeout, it's highly probable that the error is due to a timeout error. So configure the timeout value to a high value.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @BenArnao in your file httpd.conf add this line Timeout 400